# See if an object is an instance of a class passed through a string

Tags: java, reflection

I imagine that there has to be some way to use reflection to do what I want to do.

I need to be able to take a string at runtime that is of a certain class, for example:

```
string s = "mypackage.MySuperClass"
```

Then I may have an object of some type. It could be one of the following:

```
mypackage.MySuperClass obj = new mypackage.MySuperClass();
```

or

```
mypackage.MySubClass obj2 = new mypackage.MySubClass();
```

or

```
someotherpackage.SomeOtherClass obj3 = new someotherpackage.SomeOtherClass();
```

What I need to do is see if an object (which its type is determined at runtime), is equal to the string s (which is also determined at runtime via completely different means).

In the cases above I would want obj and obj2 to be the same type as s (since MySubClass is a subclass of MySuperClass), and obj3 would not.

Is there an easy way to do this in java? Possibly something using instanceOf?

Comment: (Note that class names are not unique in Java.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like you want something like this:

```
boolean isInstance(Object o, String className) {
    try {
        Class clazz = Class.forName(className);
        return clazz.isInstance(o);
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Or you could do it the other way round - take o's class (`o.getClass()`), find all ancestor classes and compare their names to `className`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Class.forName(String className)` to get the `Class` based on the string value passed in.

If all you're concerned with is whether it is an instance of a particular class, you can then call `isInstance(Object o)` on the `Class` to test whether a the parameter is an instance of the class.

If you actually need an object of the class, you can call `newInstance()` on the `Class`.  You can then test the resulting object with `instanceOf` against another object.